# Groovy ifs - how to do it better (rewriting code from Java to Groovy)

Tags: groovy

Let's assume that we have such code in java:

```
if(A) { return X }
if(B) { return Y }
return Z
```

How to rewrite it in groovy?

We can't write like this because it isn't working. We can also write like this:

```
if(A) {    
   return X
}
else {
 if(B) return Y
 else return Z
}
```

but it isn't quite elegant. Any ideas?

Comment: Why isn't the first example working?

Comment: please be exact, "it isn't working" is too vague. the solution with the conditional operator is going to do the same thing as the example code. you'll have better chances of getting relevant help if your question has specifics.

Comment: @g9023734 does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with ternary operator:

```
def X = 1
def Y = 2
def Z = 3

def A = null
def B = 1

assert 2 == A ? X : B ? Y : Z

A = 1
B = null

assert 1 == A ? X : B ? Y : Z

A = null
B = null

assert 3 == A ? X : B ? Y : Z
```

Comment: Actually, this is the ternary conditional statement, elvis operator is '?:' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator